# Zero initialization of std::vector<std::array<double,10>>

Tags: c++, vector, initialization, stdarray

Consider the following code

```
std::vector<std::array<double,10>> a(10);
```

If I understand the standard correctly `a` will not be zero initialized, because
en.cppreference.com on std::vector constructors says

> 4. Constructs the container with count default-inserted instances of T. No copies are made.

So because default initializing `std::array<double, 10>` does not fill it with zeros, `a` will also not contain zeros.

Is this true?

How can I enforce zero initialization?

Will `a.data()` point to 100 continuous `double` values?

Edit:

This is the output from godbolt on gcc 10.2 with -O2

```
main:
        mov     edi, 800
        sub     rsp, 8
        call    operator new(unsigned long)
        mov     rdi, rax
        lea     rdx, [rax+800]
.L2:
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax], 0x000000000
        add     rax, 80
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax-72], 0x000000000
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax-64], 0x000000000
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax-56], 0x000000000
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax-48], 0x000000000
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax-40], 0x000000000
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax-32], 0x000000000
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax-24], 0x000000000
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax-16], 0x000000000
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax-8], 0x000000000
        cmp     rdx, rax
        jne     .L2
        mov     esi, 800
        call    operator delete(void*, unsigned long)
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
```

So it does seems to be zero initialized. Then the question remains why.

Comment: `std::vector<std::array<double,10>> a(10, {0});` should zero-initialize, I think. Treating `a.data()` as an array of 100 doubles would exhibit undefined behavior, I believe.

Comment: Maybe not the most convenient way of doing it, but couldn't you just give an initializer list as default value for the vector constructor? Such that the array are then all initialized with it: `std::vector<std::array<double,10>> a(10, {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0});`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's correct that the overload will [default insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/DefaultInsertable) elements.

But you have to keep on reading, as default insertion means that the values inserted will be [value initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), and value-initializing an aggregate (like `std::array`) will value-initialize all elements in the aggregate.

And value initialization of `double` values will be the same as [zero-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization).

So all elements in each array of the vector will be initialized to zero.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense.
Is using `a.data()` as a pointer to 100 `double` undefined behavior?

Comment: @Unlikus `a.data()` returns a pointer to the first element of the vector, which is a `std::array<double, 10>*`, not a `double*`. So no `a.data()` can't be used like that.

Comment: Nice answer! But [this cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is a bit confusing: *note that default initialization may result in indeterminate values for non-class T*.

Comment: @Unlikus `std::array<double, 10>` is a wrapper for a `double[10]`, with no other data members (since `std::array` is an aggregate), so `sizeof(std::array<double, 10>)` is guaranteed to be *at least* `sizeof(double)*10`. `std::vector` is a *contiguous* buffer of elements, where each element in this case is a `std::array<double, 10>`.  So the only guarantee is that `a(10)` would effectively be an array of 10 contiguous `std:array`s. But not guaranteed to be a contiguous buffer of 100 `double`s, because `std::array` *may* add extra padding after its inner array.

Comment: @AdrianMole So when would one get indeterminate values?

Comment: @Unlikus I'm not sure you will. The Dude's answer seems comprehensive - I'm just confused about what cppreference means.

Answer (score 1):

To be sure that your arrays are zero-initialized, you can add a 1-element initializer list as a second argument to the `a` constructor call:

```cpp
std::vector<std::array<double, 10>> a(10, { 0.0, });
```

This will initialize *each* element (array) using that list, as it will be using constructor version #3 described [here in cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

The 'value' argument used to initialize each array will use aggregate initialization ([see here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)), which will zero-initialize any 'missing' values in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as it is shown in the demonstrative program below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::array<double,10>> v(10, { {} } );
    
    for ( const auto &a : v )
    {
        for ( const auto &item : a )
        {
            std::cout << item << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```